# How to use IE8.js for ie6?

Tags: javascript, html, layout, internet-explorer-6

My website looks great in IE8 but when i test it in IE6, it looks crappy. The alignment is off and the transparent png is not transparent. I tried to use the IE8.js by Dean Edwards but it is not working? What am i doing wrong here? Btw, the alignment problem is exactly as if i didn't have a DOCTYPE but i definitely do have. Any help please? I've validated my webpage and it is 0 error 0 warning.

My code summary:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8">
  <!--[if lt IE 8]><script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.0    
  (beta3)/IE8.js" type="text/javascript"></script><![endif]-->

  <!--My other javascript files//-->
</head>

<body>
  <!--html elements//-->
</body>

</html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have found Dean Edwards IE scripts are not an *instant relief* from IE6 problems.

I would research each bug on [positioniseverything.net/explorer.html](http://positioniseverything.net/explorer.html), become familiar with what triggers it, and then apply the necessary fix.

Answer (score 0):

Dexter, unfortunately you have stumbled into the world of IE6.  You will need to employ quite a few hacks, tricks and duct tape in order to get it to behave properly.